# Two movieclips in ADOBE FLASH CS5 hits

Tags: flash, object, flash-cs5

I have two movieclips A and B 
when the movieclip A hits the movieclip B , I want the movieclip A to be removed
what code should i write for this flash problem ?

Answer (score 0):

if you've got to the point that they really hit and you wanted to remove A

```
A.parent.removeChild(A);
```